# Making the Google Map Markers Move

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps-markers

I made an aspx page that has a Google Map that populates the location of the marker using the MSSQL Server and I have an android app that is updating the latitude and longitude of one object.

I wanted to move the markers once the latitude and longitude of the marker has been changed in the table.

Here is my javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
var MapObjectMarkers = [
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMapObjectMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
         {
            "title": '<%# Eval("mapObjectName") %>',
            "lat": '<%# Eval("indexedLatitude") %>',
            "lng": '<%# Eval("indexedLongitude") %>',
            "description": '<%# Eval("mapObjectDescription") %>',
            "type": '<%# Eval("mapObjectTypeName") %>',
            "iconpath": '<%# Eval("mapObjectIconFileName") %>',
         }

</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
function loadMapObjects() {
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

};
var fullBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
for (i = 0; i < MapObjectMarkers.length; i++) {
    var data = MapObjectMarkers[i]      
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var iconhandler = new google.maps.MarkerImage(data.iconpath);
    fullBounds.extend(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        icon: iconhandler,
        optimized: false


    });

    map.fitBounds(fullBounds);
    (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent("Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br>Longitude: " + data.lat + "    <br>Description: " + data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })
    (marker, data);
}
window.onload = function() {
    loadMapObjects();
}
</script>
```

In this script i already populated the markers on the map via on.load event.

My question is how can update the markers in the aspx page every time there is a changes in the table so it will looks like moving.

Thank you! :D